# How to dynamically add columns to a DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to dynamically add columns to a DataFrame from a Seq of String.

Here's an example : the source dataframe is like:

```scala
+-----+---+----+---+---+
|id | A | B  | C  | D  |
+-----+---+----+---+---+
|1 |toto|tata|titi|    |
|2 |bla |blo |   |     |
|3 |b   | c  |  a |  d |
+-----+---+----+---+---+
```

I also have a Seq of String which contains name of columns I want to add. If a column already exists in the source DataFrame, it must do some kind of difference like below :

The Seq looks like :

```
val columns = Seq("A", "B", "F", "G", "H")
```

The expectation is:

```
+-----+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+
|id | A | B  | C  | D  | F | G | H |
+-----+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+
|1 |toto|tata|titi|tutu|null|null|null
|2 |bla |blo |   |     |null|null|null|
|3 |b   | c  |  a |  d |null|null|null|
+-----+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+
```

What I've done so far is something like this :

```
val difference = columns diff sourceDF.columns
val finalDF = difference.foldLeft(sourceDF)((df, field) => if (!sourceDF.columns.contains(field)) df.withColumn(field, lit(null))) else df)
  .select(columns.head, columns.tail:_*)
```

But I can't figure how to do this using Spark efficiently in a more simpler and easier way to read ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: what about using `difference.foreach(x->df=df.withColumn(x,lit(null)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way using `Seq.diff`, single `select` and `map` to generate your final column list:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, col}


val newCols = Seq("A", "B", "F", "G", "H")

val updatedCols = newCols.diff(df.columns).map{ c => lit(null).as(c)}

val selectExpr = df.columns.map(col) ++ updatedCols

df.select(selectExpr:_*).show

// +---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
// | id|   A|   B|   C|   D|   F|   G|   H|
// +---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
// |  1|toto|tata|titi|null|null|null|null|
// |  2| bla| blo|null|null|null|null|null|
// |  3|   b|   c|   a|   d|null|null|null|
// +---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

First we find the diff between newCols and df.columns this gives us: `F, G, H`. Next we transform each element of the list to `lit(null).as(c)` via `map` function. Finally, we concatenate the existing and the new list together to produce `selectExpr` which is used for the `select`.

Comment: Note that by default Spark uses case insensitive column naming. A simple `Seq.diff` will fail to distinguish column names that are treated by Spark as the same but are different in their case.

Answer (score 2):

Below will be optimised way with your logic.

```
scala> df.show
+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|   A|   B|   C|   D|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|toto|tata|titi|null|
|  2| bla| blo|null|null|
|  3|   b|   c|   a|   d|
+---+----+----+----+----+

scala> val Columns  = Seq("A", "B", "F", "G", "H")

scala> val newCol =  Columns filterNot df.columns.toSeq.contains

scala> val df1 =  newCol.foldLeft(df)((df,name) => df.withColumn(name, lit(null)))
scala> df1.show()
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| id|   A|   B|   C|   D|   F|   G|   H|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1|toto|tata|titi|null|null|null|null|
|  2| bla| blo|null|null|null|null|null|
|  3|   b|   c|   a|   d|null|null|null|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

> If you do not want to use foldLeft then you can use RunTimeMirror which will be faster. Check Below Code.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror
scala> import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

scala> df.show
+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|   A|   B|   C|   D|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|toto|tata|titi|null|
|  2| bla| blo|null|null|
|  3|   b|   c|   a|   d|
+---+----+----+----+----+


scala> def compile[A](code: String): DataFrame => A = {
     |     val tb = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
     |     val tree = tb.parse(
     |       s"""
     |          |import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
     |          |import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
     |          |def wrapper(context:DataFrame): Any = {
     |          |  $code
     |          |}
     |          |wrapper _
     |       """.stripMargin)
     | 
     |     val fun = tb.compile(tree)
     |     val wrapper = fun()
     |     wrapper.asInstanceOf[DataFrame => A]
     |   }


scala> def  AddColumns(df:DataFrame,withColumnsString:String):DataFrame = {
     |     val code =
     |       s"""
     |          |import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
     |          |import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
     |          |import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
     |          |var data = context.asInstanceOf[DataFrame]
     |          |data = data
     |       """ + withColumnsString +
     |         """
     |           |
     |           |data
     |         """.stripMargin
     | 
     |     val fun = compile[DataFrame](code) 
     |     val res = fun(df)
     |     res
     |   }


scala> val Columns = Seq("A", "B", "F", "G", "H")     
scala> val newCol =  Columns filterNot df.columns.toSeq.contains

scala> var cols = ""      
scala>  newCol.foreach{ name =>
     |  cols = ".withColumn(\""+ name + "\" , lit(null))" + cols
     | }

scala> val df1 = AddColumns(df,cols)
scala> df1.show
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| id|   A|   B|   C|   D|   H|   G|   F|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1|toto|tata|titi|null|null|null|null|
|  2| bla| blo|null|null|null|null|null|
|  3|   b|   c|   a|   d|null|null|null|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the foldLeft function ? According to my spark history server, this function slows up my job for a reason I don't understand :/

Comment: If you  do not want to use then you can use runtime mirroring and execute all withColumns,  Ref: https://www.programcreek.com/scala/scala.reflect.runtime.universe

Comment: The likely reason for the `foldLeft()` slowdown is that a full plan analysis is performed on every iteration. Refactor to `df.select(col("*") +: newCols.map(name => lit(null).as(name)): _*)` for a single analysis pass.

Comment: @sim Yes I agree with you. That is a reason I have used only withColumn with df which will not take time, I guess.

Comment: `df.withColumn(name, c)` is equivalent to `df.select(col("*"), c.as(name))` when `name` is not in `df.columns`. Therefore, where possible (where the columns added are independent of each other), it is always faster to use a single `select` instead of many `withColumn`, no matter how they are issued: hard-coded, in a loop, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys ! I wasn't aware of the select technique, that's what I needed :)